# Multiple excel data copy into one excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, csv

I have multiple CSV file data i need to copy all CSV data into one excel based on the cell value Like
Source excel sheet1 B2:C2 to till end row data i need to copy Target Excel Sheet3 Column B2:C2 Till end like that there is a several workbook into one workbook copy

```
 Sub Copy_Paste()
  Dim Openfile As String ' Openfile
  Dim lstrow As Long, lCol As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim temp As Excel.Workbook
  Dim temp1 As Excel.Workbook


    lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End("AI").Column
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To lstrow
     For j = B To lCol

      'Open The Workbook FME CSV File
             Set temp1 = Workbooks.Open(ws.Cells("2" & j).Value)



                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets ("Main")
                              'Activate the destination worksheet
                               Set temp = Workbooks.Open(Range("H" & i).Value)
                               Sheets.Range("E" & i).Activate
                                'copy the data
                                 temp1.Range("B:C").Copy 'need to copy the data B2&C2 to till End column
                               'Select the target range
                              ThisWorkbook.Range("L").Select
                              'Paste in the target destination
                              temp.Range("B2:C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                  Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    temp1.Save
                    temp1.Close
                     Next j ' Once Column Cell empty goto next row
                     Next i
             End Sub
```

Comment: Super user is not a script writing service, but we can help you when you get stuck. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you provide your sample data?

Comment: @Lee Please check my code. In the Main workbook contains data's (means which excel need to open, Which column need to copy ) to the another workbook specified tab name and Column Name

Comment: @spikey_richie I can tried rows copied to into other excel but now i need to copy different columns once column should empty then go next row again same process

Comment: @ShriharshaHunsur, tell me whether the SOURCE Sheet 1 has CSV data or  the Workbook is CSV and you want to copy From Sheet to Sheet or Sheet to another WBook !!

Comment: @RajeshS source(temp1) excel CSV

Comment: @ShriharshaHunsur, could you share file on Drop box!!

Comment: @RajeshS I kept the file in Google Drive please check before start please read the txt file read me 1st file . 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UWFsUv5XNqXebDCuNubDSdgGFQ0H7SVW?usp=sharing